# How to divided 1 list to 3 - python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list:

```
a = [0.42857142857142855, 0.5714285714285714, 0.5714285714285714, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855, 0.5714285714285714, 0.5714285714285714, 0.4285714285714286, 0.5714285714285714, 0.4285714285714286, 0.5714285714285714, 0.4285714285714286, 0.4285714285714286, 0.4285714285714286, 0.4285714285714286]
```

so I want divided like this and multiply it like this:

```
[[0.42857142857142855, 0.5714285714285714, 0.5714285714285714, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855], [0.5714285714285714, 0.5714285714285714, 0.4285714285714286, 0.5714285714285714, 0.4285714285714286], [0.5714285714285714, 0.4285714285714286, 0.4285714285714286, 0.4285714285714286, 0.4285714285714286]]
```

and the multiply in every index:

```
[0.42857142857142855, 0.5714285714285714, 0.5714285714285714, 0.42857142857142855, 0.42857142857142855]
[0.5714285714285714, 0.5714285714285714, 0.4285714285714286, 0.5714285714285714, 0.4285714285714286]
[0.5714285714285714, 0.4285714285714286, 0.4285714285714286, 0.4285714285714286, 0.4285714285714286]
the multiply:
[0.14993752,0.079966681,0.149937526,0.149937526,0.03331945]
```

How can I do that with python?

Comment: Have you tried something? Also, could you rewrite your example with integers, it will be easier to read and the solution will be exactly the same.

Comment: try this,
b=[]
l=len(a)//3
for i in range(l):
    b.append(a[i]*a[i+l]*a[i+2*l])

print(b)

Comment: @srimadhan11 to format code in comments, use the `  character, enclosing the code in them. Like this: `b=[]` `l=len(a)//3 for i in range(l):` `b.append(a[i]*a[i+l]*a[i+2*l])` `print(b)`

Comment: got you, @Artemis Fowl

Answer (score 0):

This should be the right answer

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
my_new_list = [i * 5 for i in my_list]

>>> print(my_new_list)
[5, 10, 15, 20, 25]
```

Answer (score 0):

First, we divide the list in three slices.

```
def get_slices(lst, n=3):
    slice_len = len(lst) // n
    return [lst[slice_len * i: slice_len * (i + 1)] for i in range(n)]

get_slices([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])  # [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

Then with `reduce` we can multiply elements in each slice.

```
# from functools import reduce  # reduce must be imported in Python3
from operator import mul

def mult(nums):
    return [reduce(mul, t, 1) for t in zip(*nums)]
```

Here are both functions working together.

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

mult(get_slices(l))  # [2, 12, 30]
```